# Вывод на экран адресов памяти для типа char

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки

Есть следующая ф-я.

```
int main()
{
    bool arr[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cout << &arr[i] << "   ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    char arr2[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cout << &arr2[i] << "   ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Почему при массиве из char выводятся непонятные символы, а не 16-ричные числа?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оператор `cout << c`; где `с` имеет тип `char*`, считает, что `с` - нуль-терминированная сишная строка. Чтобы вывести адрес типа `char*`, нужно привести данный тип к `void*`, например: `cout << (void*)c;`

Comment: Т.е. можно сказать, что это особенность типа char, т.к. с другими типами всё нормально?

Comment: Да, это особенность char*, с указателями на другой тип всё хорошо работает.

Comment: это наследие от чистого си. Добавляйте `(void*) ` и в большинстве случаев все будет так, как Вы ожидаете. Возможно (это нужно проверить) будут проблемы с адресами функций классов (некоторые называют это "методами", но это не правильно - в с++ нет методов).

Comment: В чистом си для печати адреса используем

     printf("%p", &arr2[i]);

и никаких проблем с типами (создаваемых С++ классом ostream), естественно, не видим.

Answer (score 1):

к вышесказанному прибавлю - вот так можно получить адреса ячеек массива из типа char:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    bool arr[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cout << &arr[i] << "   ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    char arr2[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cout << &arr2 + i << "   "; // получаем адреса с помощью адресной арифметики
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, только стоить также отметить, что с двумерным массивом такое не прокатит)

Comment: @usk-dima а почему не прокатит, память-то линейная, просто подумать надо, как мне кажется.

Comment: Конечно, можно, @perfect. 

Для массивов любой размерности. Ведь все элементы размещаются в памяти последовательно, друг за другом. Только надо знать размерность по каждому из измерений (можно, кроме последнего (или первого, это с какого конца посмотреть)).

Если порисуете немного, то легко напишите формулу.